# Set String to a range

Tags: excel, vba

I have column S & U with Names. In Column Q i have the customer type (O for organization & P for personal). For all the customer Q, i want to compare the first 20 characters of the column S and column U and if they match, get the value "ok" in column V. i have done a code, but its giving me compile error in the line - str = Worksheets("ORD_CS").Range(Left("S:S"), 20). Can some help me in fixing this code. Thanks

```
Sub Macro1()
'
'Match Organization names
'

'
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim str As String, str1 As String

    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ORD_CS")
    LR = sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    str = Worksheets("ORD_CS").Range(Left("S:S"), 20)
    str1 = Worksheets("ORD_CS").Range(Left("U:U"), 20)

    With sht
            For i = 8 To LR
                If CStr(.Range("Q" & i).Value) = "O" Then
                    If str = str1 Then
                        Range("V" & i).Value = "ok"
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear, could you explain what you're trying to do (step by step). I "fixed" the compile error, but that won't solve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're selecting your substring the wrong way. You want to replace:

```
str = Worksheets("ORD_CS").Range(Left("S:S"), 20)
str1 = Worksheets("ORD_CS").Range(Left("U:U"), 20)
```

With:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
'Match Organization names
'

'
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim str As String, str1 As String

    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ORD_CS")
    LR = sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    With sht
            For i = 8 To LR
                If CStr(.Range("Q" & i).Value) = "O" Then
                    str = Left(.Range("S" & i).Value, 20)
                    str1 = Left(.Range("U" & i).Value, 20)
                    If str = str1 Then
                        Range("V" & i).Value = "ok"
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Currently, you're trying to select 20 characters from a range. And this string selection needs to be done in-loop, not at the beginning of the loop, unless I don't understand your question.

Comment: Replaced with your code, but getting "runtime error - type mismatch".

Comment: Left will not work with multiple cell ranges.  The OP will need to loop and test each individually.

Comment: @user2574 I edited my post, but I'm not sure if that's what you want to do, checking for each row 2 values, then saying OK